how to make a win function tic tac to toe js
I'm trying to make a tic-tac-toe game, but I don't know how to implement a win system. What I mean is that I need to create a system that can detect when a player wins by filling three squares in a row. I'm not sure how to do that. Could someone please help me?
I've created a winConditions array where I've listed all the possible winning combination
playerOneInput = document.getElementById(`playerOne`)
playerTwoInput = document.getElementById(`playerTwo`)
const statusText = document.getElementById(`statusText`)
const startGameBtn = document.getElementById(`startGameBtn`)
let currentPlayer = ``
const winConditions = [
    [1, 2, 3], // Top row
    [4, 5, 6], // Middle row
    [7, 8, 9], // Bottom row
    [1, 4, 7], // Left column
    [2, 5, 8], // Middle column
    [3, 6, 9], // Right column
    [1, 5, 9], // Main diagonal
    [3, 5, 7] // Secondary diagonal
]


// Fazer a função para alterar os jogadores a cada turno

function switchPlayer() {
   if (currentPlayer === playerOneInput.value) {
       currentPlayer = playerTwoInput.value
    } else {
       currentPlayer = playerOneInput.value
    }
    statusText.textContent = `Turno de ${currentPlayer}`
}


function playerName() {
    startGameBtn.addEventListener(`click`, () => {
        if (playerOneInput.value && playerTwoInput.value) {
            currentPlayer = playerOneInput.value
            switchPlayer()
            startGameBtn.disabled = true
        } else {
            alert(`Por favor, insira os nomes dos dois jogadores`)
        }
    })

}


function clickSquare() {

    const cells = document.querySelectorAll(`.cell`)

    cells.forEach(cell => {
        cell.addEventListener(`click`, () => {
            // Verifica se a célula já está marcada
            if (cell.textContent === `` && currentPlayer) {
                let marker
            } if (currentPlayer === playerOneInput.value) {
                marker = `O`
            } else {
                marker = `X`
            }
            const span = document.createElement(`span`)
            span.textContent = marker
            if (marker === `X`) {
                span.style.color = `#FF0000`
            } else {
                span.style.color = `#0000FF`
            }



                cell.appendChild(span)
                switchPlayer()


        })
    })


}

clickSquare()
playerName()


You should try to create a function that iterates over your winConditions array and compares each array there for correct entries, if each array has a truthy return, you have a winner, if each array has one that is not truthy, no winner. If you can't get it right, post your try and then ask for assistance. If you have already tried, post your code in your question.

One difficulty is that your "board" is only stored in spans - so to "read" the board to determine if it's a win, you have to read the "spans".  Instead, separate the board logic from the display, then update the display to reflect the board.   So, eg your cell would have data-board-idx="1" (top left using 1-based as per the win-conditions) then the click event would be board[board_idx] = 'X' (as an example) - rather than creating a new span each time - you then have a refreshBoard() function which updates the cells based on the board array.

You need to make a function that loops through each row of your winConditions.
Inside of that you need another loop that compares each item in your win conditions to the contents of your cells having corresponding indexes and keeps count of how many are Xs and Os there are.   If it counts 3 of either, it should trigger your win function.  Lastly, you will need to subtract 1 from all of the values in your winConditions matrix, because when you make your cells array, the index IDs start at 0, not 1.

@Nosajimiki that's a design choice, not a requirement.   OP could instead keep it 1-based by adding 1 to the cell .index (if going down that route)  (but will likely need to do one or the other if using the DOM as the active board)

@fdomn-m True, you can do it either way, but you keep your code less complex/confusing if you treat your cells as 0-8 instead of 1-9 because it means you don't need to write in an offset.
